# ViewChild('inputState', { read: MatAutocompleteTrigger})

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material, viewchild

I am using an Angular Material AutoComplete Component and I want to launch an action when its pannel is closed.

It is working fine with Angular 5: [demo](https://izno-angular5-matautocompletetrigger.stackblitz.io) *(look at the console)*

But it does not work with Angular 8: [demo](https://izno-angular8-matautocompletetrigger.stackblitz.io) *(look at the console)*

The **@ViewChild** does not find any element despite I have updated the code from

```
@ViewChild('inputState', {read: MatAutocompleteTrigger}) trigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger;
```

to

```
@ViewChild('inputState', {read: MatAutocompleteTrigger, static: false}) trigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger;
```